# ¿Cómo puedo copiar una cadena de caracteres en otra muchas veces sin generar error?

Tags: c

esta es una parte de mi programa y el error esta en la función `strcpy`, cuando la comento
compila bien pero cuando no el programa me dice

```
El sistema no puede ejecutar el programa especificado.
```

he intentando asignarlo directamente con = y me aparece `error: assignment to expression with array type`

```
char country[100];  
char    line[100];
char      code[3];
int lowerRank = 0;
int upperRank = 0;

    for (int id = 0; id < sizeDatabase; id++){

        fgets(line,100,pointerFile);
        lowerRank = atoi(strtok(line,","));
        upperRank = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
        strcpy(code,strtok(NULL,","));
        
        printf("[%d]%d  ",id,lowerRank);
        printf("[%d]%d\n",id,upperRank);
        printf("[%d]%s\n",id,code);

     }
```